# How to put value(data) into html attribute with ReactJS and ReactIntl

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a internationalization with ReactJS and ReactIntl

Usually, for this i used a code like this:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancelDelete}><FormattedMessage id="confirm" defaultMessage="NO" /></button>
```

But, now i need to put data inside a html tag, like span in attribute title.

```
<span className="glyphicon-green glyphicon glyphicon-ok" onClick={this.addTag} title="Add">
```

My question: is there any way how to do this with ReactJS and ReactIntl?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<FormattedMessage .../>` return a span element with a text.

I used this

```
contextTypes:{
  intl: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

And this

```
<span
    className="glyphicon-green
    glyphicon
    glyphicon-ok"
    onClick={this.addTag}
    title={this.context.intl.messages.addTitle}>
</span>
```